# Headless JavaScript testing in ree + cucumber

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, ruby-enterprise-edition, headless-browser

Is there a way to do headless javascript testing in ree (Ruby Enterprise Edition)?

I've seen celerity/culerity/capybara, which work with jruby + HTMLUnit, but I can't seem to get it working with ree. When I simply try to annotate my cucumber test with `@culerity` under ree, I get `jruby: command not found`, which of course makes sense, because I'm running under ree, not jruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been looking at different libraries to do headless javascript testing.

I have tried [akephalos](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/akephalos), based on HTMLUnit, which was really promising, but I was unable to get tests working that worked with selenium.

I am now using [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit), and it works flawlessly. You will need to install Qt before installing the gem.
But once that is done (and on ubuntu it is really easy to install), you just add the gem to your `Gemfile`

```
gem "capybara-webkit"
```

And set your Capybara Javascript driver to webkit:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

And you are good to go. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use capybara-webkit or run selenium with Xvfb - see this [post](http://iafonov.github.com/blog/setup-jenkins-to-run-headless-selenium.html) with explanations on how to set it up.

Comment: `capybara-webkit` and `selenium` with xvfb both work fine, `capybara-webkit` is dead easy to setup, but i found `selenium` to be more stable.

Answer (score 1):

take a look also at poltergeist

https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist